# Camel sftp doesn't poll on Unix more than 2 levels deep

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, spring-camel, camel-ftp

Camel sftp is unable to poll more than 2 levels deep when the java code runs on Linux, but it works fine on Windows.

For example, polling files from

`sftp://user@domain:22/folder1/folder2?...`

works on both Unix and Windows. But, when I use something like

`sftp://user@domain:22/folder1/folder2/folder3?...`,

the route is always started yet the route running on Unix doesn't get the files in folder 3.

```
Route: route22 started and consuming from:sftp://user@domain:22/folder1/folder2/folder3?...
```

The sftp is to the same Unix machine and the same paths are used.

I have tried with stepwise true and false, as well as with recursive.

Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: What happens when you add `jschLoggingLevel=TRACE` to the route URI?  Do you see anything happening in the logs which could shed more light into what's being found in that directory?

Comment: The problem was caused by the quartz trigger configured on this route. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a quartz trigger (attached to the route) that became corrupted. That happend because of a camel bug that makes camel unable to reconcile triggers when running in cluster mode if they fail due to database reasons.